# rowedit grid with sync

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs-stores

I try to implement a general rowediting grid like [this example](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/kitchensink/#row-editing), with the difference that I would like to sync the changes with the server backend. Until now, I can add a new line with `onRoweditAdd`.

```
Ext.define('Mb.view.base.RoweditListController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.roweditlist',
    onRoweditAdd: function(me){
        var grid = me.up('panel'),
            edit = grid.editingPlugin,
            store = grid.getStore(),
            record = store.getModel().create({id: 0});
        edit.cancelEdit()
        store.insert(0, record)
        edit.startEdit(record, 0)
    },
    editRowedit: function(editor, ctx) {
        var store = ctx.grid.getStore();
        store.sync()
    }
})
```

The problem is that `store.sync()` does not send a `create` request to the server, but an `update` request. It looks like `store.insert(0, record)` is not accounted for. Only the modification done by the user is synched. What could be the culprit ?

Comment: I have tried to reproduce, however, [in my case, only Create is called, never Update. Weird.](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/20j3)

Comment: Even  I have tried and not able to reproduce it please share fiddle if possible.

Comment: @Alexander I found a workaround, look at my answer. If you understand why creating a record with id 0 is not allowed, put it as your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @RonakPatel I found a workaround, look at my answer. If you understand why creating a record with id 0 is not allowed, put it as your answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By giving an existing `id` in a record, ExtJS assumes this record already exist in your store and has to be updated. If you don't give an id then it supposes it is a newly created record and will go the create route. This comes from the assumption that you use a generated ID strategy (which you generally should) and thus you would never provide IDs yourself upon creation.

Under the hood, ExtJS marks the record as phantom: true or false. Phantom records are the ones that only exist in the front end and haven't been persisted yet. Creating a record with no `id` will mark it as phantom whereas creating a record with an id already provided will not mark it as phantom and will not trigger a create call but an update instead

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. This is a difference with ExtJs 4, where `id==0` meant *new record*

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I was not able to create a fiddle that reproduces the problem.

I solved it by changing this line:

```
record = store.getModel().create({id: 0});
```

to

```
record = store.getModel().create({});
```

The problem has to do something with the new implementation of the record ids since ExtJs 5. But I cannot explain it...

The creation of a new record with `id: 0` must no longer be supported in ExtJs 6.

Answer (score 1):

I found that in `Ext.data.Model` `idProperty` is used as unique key to identify record. By default it has`id` field set. If you provide it duplicate, then it will cause issue in `store`.

This description  has written in ExtJS doc

```
The data values for this field must be unique or there will be id value collisions in the Ext.data.Store.
Defaults to:
'id'
```

Please refer [link](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.data.Model.html#cfg-idProperty)